# Trying to fix a broken stand mixer

Tags: pcb, motor, ac, triac, dip

I have an old electrolux standmixer which I use frequently. A couple of weeks ago I was making bread and the stand mixer were kneading the dough for around 20-25 min and then I turned it off to check the dough. After 10 seconds I tried to turn it back on but it wouldn't start. Since I am a student I cant really afford to buy a new one and since I have an interest in electronics I though I would try to fix it. I screwed the machine apart and there are three main components which are the switch, the circuit board and the motor. I tested the switch and motor and they're both working so the fault must be in the circuit board which is in the picture below. [image]

The two leftmost pins in the top left corner are the pins for the motor and the third is the live wire coming from the switch. Ground is the one in the other corner. Here is another from the back [image]

I tried following the paths on the circuit board and scetched up some of the main circuit which included the motor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVetQL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So it's at this point i'm a out on deep water. I've only had a couple of electronics courses so I'm a bit unsure as to what the problem could be. The three arm thingy was a btb10-600b which is after a quick google search turned out to be a 10A triac. The "signal arm" on the triac is connected directly to to pin 16 on the U2010b phase control circuit which is the trigger output pin. I tried shorting the two current leading legs in the triac and the motor span, which leads me to think that either the triac or the U2010B is the problem.

I mainly thought the triac might be the problem due to overheating or something so I soldered on a btb16-600bw triac. I tried to compare the datasheets and they looked quite similar other than the 10 or 16 A rating so I gave it a shot but it still didn't work. I have ordered a U2010B-MY 16 pin which is coming in the mail soon.

So finally my questions:
1:
Does it sound probable that it's either the triac or the U2010b that are to blame or could it be e.g. one of the resistors or capacitors. My analogy is that the triac is a gate ant the U2010B controls the gate so if one of them doesn't work the gate wont open. But could it also be that if e.g. one of the capacitors were broken then the U2010B would never send the signal? Is it more likely that the U2010B is broken or the triac?

2:
I struggled with finding the correct part in close proximity to were I live, so I ordered the btb16-600bw instead of the btb10-600b and the U2010B-MY instead of the U2010B. They look quite similar in the datasheets but are the differences so noticable so it might not work even if I change out the defect part. e.g. like if the triac was fine did I screw something up by changing that part to a btb16-600bw?

3:
Also have anyone ever experienced electrical things working fine and the suddenly wont turn on again after prolonged use? What could be the reason for the broken component? If i fix it should I be careful with too heavy load to avoid heat or could it be something else than heat, like the fact that the machine is pretty old and that it could be just wear and tear of an old part?

Comment: Did you check the POWER SWITCH works???   If you put 120VAC on the motor directly, does it spin??? (I.e. have you proved the motor is good??)

Comment: Yes I tried this:) It works

Comment: How about contacting Electrolux?  They're still in business.  You never know   ;)

Comment: Also try hitting every solder point with new fresh solder.   The joints can look good, but not be ("Cold solder joint").   Last try the 'chopstick test'.  While it's powered up, (carefully) push on every component with a wooden stick, see if it suddenly starts working when you touch something.

Comment: A problem is that it's a very old machine and another company own the rights to the patents now(ankarsrum). So the new company made new circuit boards which doesn't  fit this and the old company apparently doesn't know how to fix it either becuase it's such an old machine. They said they might be able to provide help if a could go to one of their stores or something like that(which there of course aren't any of in my city).

Comment: OK - Glad you tried it!    My money is on the U2010.   I agree the triac you selected should be compatible enough.   Hope that does it for ya!

Comment: Thanks! I will try it as soon as it arrives:)

Comment: You can probably find spare motor control PCBs pretty cheap which will be a LOT less work than debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

yes. This is one of those ciruits which powers directly from mains, with no isolation transformer. Not so nice, but common on cheap electronics where the equipment body is all plastic.

Be very careful working on it, because you can have high voltages in the circuit even after you power off, due to charge stored on the capacitor!

A common problem in these circuits is either the rectification diode or especially the smoothing cap (large grey one by the look) which sometimes die after many years due to high voltage stress.

If you replace the cap make sure you use one rated for direct mains connection!!

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will certainly look into the smoothing cap and diode but one question? Since the motor ran when I shorted the arms of the triac then the triac has to be a part of the problem. Could that be caused by the U2010B not getting a signal to open the triac because of the capacitor or diode being broken?

Comment: no, the diode/cap circuit typically gives rough DC (can be very high if you are on 240V!!) which is often dropped rather crudely via resistors etc to power the triac drive circuit. The motor itself is powered straight from the mains via the inductor. So if you force the triac on  the motor will run even though the DC cct is faulty.

Comment: another caution - do NOT try to investigate this cct with a scope! the whole thing is running ref one side of your AC line, there is no GND ref, and if you try to hook up a scope you will get magic smoke and nasty "surprises" of a bad sort!

Comment: So the diode cap circuit could(if broken) give a rough dc voltage that could break the U2010B? I'm wondering because from the pcb if you follow the path from the "signal arm" of the triac it only goes to the U2010B and nowhere else. If the U2010B is working perfectly then could the reason be that it is now getting the correct signals to activate the motor or something like that which is why the triac isn't activated? Also can't one easily see(burn marks or something) if a capacitor or resistor is broken(as to exclude some possibilities of which parts it could be)?

Comment: more likely the cap is open circuit (i.e. a 0uF cap) and there is no DC, rather a nasty ac signal. Or the diode is open. Or even one of these measures OK with a meter but breaks down under voltage (rare but possible). Problem is that sometimes one failure causes several others. I'd replace diode and cap and triac (maybe the IC too) and see if that helps - and if not, well ok, all good things come to an end ... of course you can also check resistors too. Problem is that these ccts are not nice to probe with test gear, so its a bit trial and error.

Comment: Thanks alot! One final question? This occured when the stand mixer were working hard for a prolonged amount of time and was turned off and then back on. Is a broken cct something that is known to happen with circuits under heavy load?

Comment: Maybe ... Hard to say. Could also just be age and bad luck. Also have a look and see if one of those components is a zener, that could also be part of the cheap voltage "regulator" ...

Comment: ... actually doesn't look like. Electrolytic cap could also be a suspect